# Link a URL to a position in QField

Tags: kml, pdf, qfield, hyperlink, url

I'm looking for a way to link a PDF file in my OneDrive to a position that comes from a KML file. I've already managed to do this on QGIS but once the project is transferred to QField it doesn't work.  This would be very useful for my technicians in the field.